# How can I apply group normalization after a full-connection layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

How can I apply Group Normalization after a full-connection layer? Say the output of the full-connection layer is 1024. And the group normalization layer is using 16 groups.

```py
self.gn1 = nn.GroupNorm(16, hidden_size)
h1 = F.relu(self.gn1(self.fc1(x))))
```

Am I right? How should we understand the group normalization if it is applied to the output of a full-connection layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, but let's see what happens in a small example.

The output of a fully-connected layer is usually a 2D-tensor with shape `(batch_size, hidden_size)` so I will focus on this kind of input, but remember that `GroupNorm` supports tensors with an arbitrary number of dimensions. In fact, `GroupNorm` works always on the last dimension of the tensor.

`GroupNorm` treats all the samples in the batch as independent and it creates `n_groups` from the last dimension of the tensor, as you can see from the image.

[image: GroupNorm on a (N, W, H, C) tensor]

When the input tensor is 2D, the cube in the image becomes a square because there is no third vertical dimension, so in practice the normalization is performed on fixed-size consecutive pieces of the rows of the input matrix.

Let's see an example with some code.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

batch_size = 2
hidden_size = 32
n_groups = 8
group_size = hidden_size // n_groups # = 4

# Input tensor that can be the result of a fully-connected layer
x = torch.rand(batch_size, hidden_size)

# GroupNorm with affine disabled to simplify the inspection of results
gn1 = nn.GroupNorm(n_groups, hidden_size, affine=False)
r = gn1(x)

# The rows are split into n_groups (8) groups of size group_size (4)
# and the normalization is applied to these pieces of rows.
# We can check it for the first group x[0, :group_size] with the following code
first_group = x[0, :group_size]
normalized_first_group = (first_group - first_group.mean())/torch.sqrt(first_group.var(unbiased=False) + gn1.eps)
print(r[0, :4])
print(normalized_first_group)
if(torch.allclose(r[0, :4], normalized_first_group)):
    print('The result on the first group is the expected one')
```

Comment: Good answer! Thx!